# Sharepoint - caml join with numbers

Tags: caml-query, caml

I have done a join in Caml with my list (example list A) to another list (example list B)

One of the fields in list B is a number of 2 decimal places.
However, in the view it is displaying lots of zeros as follows:
2.55000000000000

It seems to be a limitation in CAML joins. is there a way to get around it please?